# Add a column to result, which is another SELECT with dependency

Tags: mysql, sql

This one is a little bit tricky, at least to me to explain, so please, don't get mad if you don't get the point - it's likely caused by my poor explanation.

I want to get one more column from my main SELECT, which will represent number of rows from another table, suiting id of main record.

So, imagine main table, which I am selecting from. I'll call it simply **main**.

What I want to select from **main**, basically is:

```
SELECT * FROM main ORDER BY c1 ASC LIMIT 5
```

Plus I need one extra column for each row returned, which says number of rows from **side** table, matching the id:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM side WHERE m_id = main_id
```

Maybe an example will tell you a little bit more

```
      id   data1   data2           id   m_id   ...
main ----|-------|-------   side -----|------|-----
       1     aa     ab              1     1     
       2     xx     yy              2     2
       3     az     bz              3     1
                                    4     1
                                    5     3
                                    6     2
                                    7     1
                                    8     1
                                    9     2

expected result:
 id   data1   data2    num
----|-------|-------|------
  1     aa      ab      5
  2     xx      yy      3
  3     az      bz      1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to add the count is with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT m.*,
       (select count(*) from side s where s.m_id = m.main_id) as side_cnt
FROM main m
ORDER BY c1 ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

You can also do this by changing the `from` clause.  However, this method only affects the `select` part of the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was soo mad about it because I couldn't remember how I did it in the past and also was unable to find it on the net, as I didn't know how it's called or how to describe. Now I feel so stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it as a subquery:

```
SELECT m.*, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM side WHERE m_id = m.main_id ) as num FROM main m ORDER BY c1 ASC LIMIT 5
```

This basically runs a special query for each result that counts the number of matching results and displays it in the "num" column.